# Dojo Date Parse not parsing date

Tags: javascript, date, dojo, date-formatting

The date string I'm trying to parse:

`7/15/2014, 3:26 PM UTC`

The date pattern I think should be working:

`'MM/dd/YYYY, h:m a vz'`

Question: am I doing something wrong? Link to the format options here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/format.html

I'm using it like so:

```
var date = locale.parse('7/15/2014, 3:26 PM UTC', {datePattern: 'MM/dd/YYYY, h:m a vz'});
```

Comment: Have you included the library in the code? `require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale){ \\yourcode });`?  Which version of `dojo` are you using?
You can also use [`parser' library in dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/parser.html)

Comment: obviously.. and I'm using dojo 1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you use `selector: 'date'` as well. Even though you included the time, it will also use the time of your provided string.

Your date pattern is not completely true though. If you use years inside the pattern, you should use lowercase letters, for example `yyyy`.

Also, you're not using `07/15/2014` but `7/15/2014` so it's more correct to use `M/dd/yyyy` in stead of `MM/dd/yyyy`, though it does seem to work find in both examples.

The result:

```js
require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale) {
  var date = locale.parse('7/15/2014, 3:26 PM UTC', {
    datePattern: 'M/dd/yyyy, h:m a vz',
    selector: 'date'
  });
  console.log(date);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtupv55b/

Comment: That's the intended behavior for the timezones. The javascript date that is instantiated pulls the timezone from your runtime environment. Thanks, I didn't realize the date selector was necessary (I had tried both variations of the year thing, they have one in the textual documentation and another in an example).

Comment: @Paul_R I didn't know the `selector` thing either, but looking at the examples of the parse-documentation, I noticed that they all used it, so I tried setting it as well. :p